# How is "brrm" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, interjections

I find some interjections to be too tricky to pronounce.

Can anyone help me with this one? Is there any specialized dictionary that reports the pronunciation of interjections?

Comment: you can always edit your questions and answers. Click the gray [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/31613/edit) link and include all the information we need. You can also delete your comment afterwards, by hovering over it and clicking the gray X.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure **brrm** is an "interjection", but let that pass.

It's an example of [onomatopoeia](http://www.examples-of-onomatopoeia.com/). That link gives many more onomatopoeic words, but curiously it doesn't have **brrm**, which is pronounced **broom**.

Many if not most people say/write **vrrrm** for the same sound, and in both cases the word is often repeated. The precise number of **r**'s may vary, and sometimes it'll be written as, for example, **vroom vroom** (it's often intending to convey the sound of a racing car revving up).

Comment: Funny, I thought it was a contraction of *barroom*, which is either a type of saloon or an elephant fart.

Comment: I thought it was a Welsh word at first. I think @Robusto was closer.

Comment: I would argue that it's pronounced brum with option extra Rs and Ms.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Might you be a Northern British speaker, by any chance? Anyway, NGram has far more *vroom* than any other variant (it's pointless searching for *broom*). It also shows that if there's no vowel, double **r** is much more common than three or more. And if additional **m**'s are used at all, they're too rare to be reported by NGram.

Comment: No, although maybe I got the pronunciation from my mum (who is from the north). It could equally have been influenced by the children's TV show [Brum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brum_%28TV_series%29) which was set in a town near me.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Presumably you're at least aware of the more common variant **vroom[-vroom]**. Would you pronounce *that* with a short **u** as well?

Comment: I would not. Vroooooommm!